# Doing something wrong with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I am a noob trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I have created the simplest code I can think of and can't seem to get it to work. I want to populate a select. Here is the angular code:

```
var app= angular.module('selectMusic', [])

app.controller('selectCtrl',function($scope){

     $scope.types=["Artists","Genre","Album","Date","Plays"];
});
```

Here is the division in my html:

```
<div ng-control="selectCtrl">
 <select ng-model="Type" ng-options="type for type in types"/>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ng-controller instead

Comment: Console should tell you everything..